# How to enable row level security by default?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

One might forget to enable it, so I'd rather explicitly disable it for tables that don't need it.

Comment: But where's the question you're asking?

Comment: I'll rephrase: how to enable row level security by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can probably enable it by default by creating an `event trigger.`

I haven't tried this but this should be enough to get you started.

In this case you effectively have a function which runs after any CREATE TABLE and enables row level security.

The PostgreSQL docs for PostgreSQL 9.5 are at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-event-triggers.html for functions you can use to get the table info.  This looks feasible.

Answer (score 3):

Row level security can not be enabled or disabled by default. You have to `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY`. However, I don't see how you can forget it as a table is only accessible by its owner initially. If you then create a row security policy with `CREATE POLICY` you will still not have access so you'll know you did something wrong.

You can ask yourself why you have to `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY` to begin with, but that is a question for the `postgresql-devel` mailing list, not for SO.

Comment: Alright. I think it's there because of performance reasons. `COPY` commands are transformed into normal `INSERT`s when row level security is enabled. I'm sure there are other reasons. The fact that it's not enabled by default is a problem when I create a policy and `GRANT` access to a role. If I haven't run `ENABLE ROW SECURITY`, then the policy won't be applied.